# Select or Copy three 3 non-adjacent cells

Tags: excel, vba, cell, copy-paste

How can I copy 3 non-adjacent cells using `ActiveCell.Row`?

```
Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row, "C" & ActiveCell.Row, "E" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy
```

**Update:**
*For further info follow - https://youtu.be/zjF7oLLgtms*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To simplify things a little:

```
Range(Replace("A?,C?,E?", "?", ActiveCell.Row)).Copy
```

Answer (score 5):

You have the `,` outside the `""`. You need to put them inside. See this

```
Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ",C" & ActiveCell.Row & ",E" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Union(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5)).Copy
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is tons of way to do this, you might read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/select-cells-rangs-with-visual-basic) it will give you better insight.

I would have done :

```
Sub test()

Set x = Application.Union(Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row), Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row), Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row))
x.Copy

End Sub
```