# How to store cell coordinates into a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

so I want to copy values from a Range, but instead of using the Range such as B1:B15, I'd like to store the address of B1 into a variable and the address of B15 into another variable

```vb
ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B15, D1:D15, F1:AJ15").Copy
```

B1 should be `Cells(1,2)` and B15 should be `Cells(15,2)`.

B1 is a static variable, which never changes.

B15 is my last row in the Worksheet, and the number 15 I got using the function:

```
Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Sorry but what are you trying to get? You can store `B1` doing something like `Set rng1 = Range("B1")` and about last row, because it's changing, you need to update it every time it changes, calling it again. Something like `LAstRow=Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`. And to call `B1:B15` you could use `Range(rng1.Address & ":B" & LastRow)`

Comment: Using your code, I get an Error Run-Time 1004.

Comment: Set rngB1 = Range("B1")
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

ActiveSheet.Range(rngB1.Address & ":B" & lastrow, "D1:D15, F1:AJ15").Copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58076069/9758194) method:

```
Sub Test()

Dim x As Long
With Sheet1'Change accordingly
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(Replace("B1:B?,D1:D?,F1:AJ?", "?", x)).Copy
End With

End Sub
```

I left out the static variable, since that never changes anyway. If need be, this can be added in nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this for B1 and B15:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet") 'change MySheet for your sheet name
        Dim MyRange As Range
        Set MyRange = .Cells(1, 2) 'This is your constant

        Dim LastCell As Range
        Set LastCell = .Cells(.rows.count, "B").End(xlUp)
    End With

End Sub
```

Edit:

For what you are asking in the comment the code would be this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet") 'change MySheet for your sheet name
        Dim lrow As Long
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B1:B" & lrow & ",D1:D" & lrow & ",F1:AJ" & lrow).Copy
    End With

End Sub
```

when you want multiple columns, you need to give a range like "A1,C1,H1". A single string comma separated all of your ranges, so you need to concatenate your variable checking the last row to that string.

Comment: How can I use this inside my code?

ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B15,D1:D15,F1:AJ15").Copy

Comment: You want to copy always the same columns just changing their own last row @AndreiMoza?

Comment: In the end I did it, thanks for your time! Have a nice day